# semodule fails to install module

Tags: selinux

I run Fedora Atomic host 29, with SELinux enforced.
The box is a few week old and run smoothly, until recently when it comes to SELinux.
Trying to solve some errors with this command:

```
# cat /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2why
```

Here is part of my output:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1566945464.600:4258): avc:  denied  { signal } for  pid=6611 comm="su" scontext=sysadm_u:sysadm_r:sysadm_su_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=sysadm_u:sysadm_r:sysadm_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tclass=process permissive=0

    Was caused by:
        Missing type enforcement (TE) allow rule.

        You can use audit2allow to generate a loadable module to allow this access.
```

Then:

```
# ausearch -c 'su' --raw | audit2allow -M my-su     
******************** IMPORTANT ***********************
To make this policy package active, execute:

semodule -i my-su.pp
# semodule -v -X 100 -i my-su.pp 
Ok: return value of 0.
Attempting to install module 'my-su.pp':
semodule:  Failed on my-su.pp!
```

How can I fix this issue with such a minimalist error message?
Thank you for help.